# Add New/Update $key and $value to an Array in WordPress

Tags: arrays, wordpress, associative-array

I am trying to add/update a new $key and $value to an existing array.

**Form input:**

```
<input name="flyer_packages[55][price][custom_price]" value="1000">
```

**Current Array:**

```
Array (
      [55] => Array (
                    [date] => 10 October 
                    [pricing_option] => true 
                    [price] => Array (
                                     [price_amount] => 3 000     
                                     [price_descriptor] => None
```

**WP function to add new meta:**

```
if (!empty ($_POST['flyer_packages'])) {
     $flyer_packages = get_post_meta($pid, 'flyer_packages', true);
     foreach ($flyer_packages as $flyer_package) {
         foreach ($flyer_package[price] as $key => $value) {
             update_post_meta( $pid, 'flyer_packages' , $_POST['flyer_packages']);
         }
     }
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Array (
      [55] => Array (
                    [date] => 10 October
                    [pricing_option] => true 
                    [price] => Array (
                                     [price_amount] => 3 000     
                                     [price_descriptor] => None
                                     [custom_price] => 1 000
```

**Actual Result:**

```
Array (
      [55] => Array (
                    [price] => Array (
                                     [custom_price] => 1 000
```

As you can see the result adds the new key and value but deletes all other keys and values in the array.

Can anybody please advise, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you're replacing the value, you have to merge arrays first

```
   if (!empty ($_POST['flyer_packages'])) {
      $flyer_packages = get_post_meta($pid, 'flyer_packages', true);
      $new_value = $_POST['flyer_packages'];
      custom_keys_recursive($new_value, $flyer_packages);   
      update_post_meta( $pid, 'flyer_packages', $flyer_packages);   
   }  

   function custom_keys_recursive($value, &$array) {
     foreach ($value as $k=>$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
          custom_keys_recursive($v, $array[$k]);
        } else {
          $array[$k] = $v;
        }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Vitali Protosovitski, I have just noticed that when re saving custom_price is converted into an array and new values are added instead of replacing: 
First save: [custom_price] => 1000 - Correct!
Subsequent saves: [custom_price] => Array ( [0] => Array [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => 1000

Comment: Updated answer with a recursive function